# How to Adjust X-Axis on Pyplot Output Graph to Proper Location?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, formatting

I'm using Pandas and Pyplot to work with surface wind gust data from CSV data. The data I pulled from the file looks good and is plotted properly, but this graph seems like it's weirdly floating above the axis for reasons unknown to me. Here's a screenshot to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

I'd like to have that plot aligned nicely along the x-axis. I'm not all that worried with the white space on the left given that my data starts in May, which I can figure out later. So my question is how can I get the graph aligned the way I want it? I've tried shifting the subplot axis, but that just enlarged the plot in the window. Also, if you're willing to provide other formatting suggestions to make this as clean and professional as possible, I'd appreciate it!

Here's the code I used to generate it:

```
#Import packages and assign to variables
import pandas as pd
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os

#Change working directory to where file is located
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("C:/Users/zrr81/Downloads/Climate Dev/Python/Synoptic Client Data")

#Read in file
data = pd.read_csv('KCDC.2019-11-01.csv')

#Build wind gust and datetime DataFrame
gust = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date_Time', 'wind_gust'])
#Drop all rows that don't contain a gust (inplace)
gust.dropna(how = 'any', inplace = True)
#Drop unit/ header row
gust = gust.drop(gust.index[0])
#Convert data types from objects to datetime and float
gust['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(gust['Date_Time'])
gust['wind_gust'] = gust['wind_gust'].astype(str).astype(float)
print(gust)      #Outputs datetime and float
print(gust.dtypes)

#Plot max wind speeds, gusts, and times
ax = plt.gca()
gust.plot(kind = 'line' , x = 'Date_Time', y = 'wind_gust', color = 'red')
#plt.plot(zw.year, zw.population)
plt.legend(['Wind gusts'])
plt.xlabel("Date Time")
plt.ylabel("Wind Gust (m/s)")
plt.title("May-Nov Maximum Wind Gusts at KCDC")
plt.show()
```

**EDIT: To clarify, I believe the y-axis is shifted up by 7.5 and needs to be shifted down to the origin (clarifying this in the title as well). I'm looking for suggestions on how to fix this

Comment: Can you explain *"how can I get the graph aligned the way I want it"* a little bit more concrete? Are you considereing somethings like `plt.ylim(bottom=7.5)`? Or `plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)`?

Comment: @JohanC I'll check into your suggestion about the ylim. It seems like the x-axis is set to a y value of 7.5 and needs to be shifted down to 0, hence why the gust below that value is appearing like a negative outlier. I'll make an edit specifying this as well